# Number of irreducible polynomials of degree 4 on $\boldsymbol{Z}_3[x]$.

Tags: ring-theory

> Find the number of irreducible polynomials of degree 4 in $\boldsymbol{Z}_3[x]$.

Not really sure what to do here, I've tried listing them all out but this seems tedious, and all I need to find is the number of irreducible polynomials, not their values. Is there perhaps a general formula for this?

Comment: How many irreducible polynomials did you find of degrees $2$, $3$, and $4$?